# Segue not working after setting up custom navigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I am performing a segue from my loadVC to containterVC in which I set up a navigationController and set it's rootViewController to mainVC

Code in viewDidLoad in containterVC:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mainVC = UIStoryboard.mainVC()  //This is an extension to UIStoryboard
    //Setting up the delegate:
    mainVC.delegate = self




    //rootViewController - ten najbardziej na dole
    myNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainVC)
    //Storing the root view as currentViewController:
    self.currentViewController = mainVC
    myNavigationController.addChildViewController(mainVC)
    self.view.addSubview(myNavigationController.view)
    addChildViewController(myNavigationController)
    myNavigationController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)


    //Trying to set up the navigation bar
    let bar = myNavigationController.navigationBar
    //Navigation bars:
    bar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    bar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    bar.translucent = false
}
```

I launch the project. And? Everything works properly.

Then I try to add these under "bar.translucent = false" line:

```
    print("statement1")
    let menuButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Menu", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "")
    print("statement2")
    let item = myNavigationController.navigationItem
    print("statement3")
    item.leftBarButtonItem = menuButton
    print("statement4")
    bar.items = [item]
    print("statement5")
```

After launching the project print statements up to 4 are displayed and the 5th is not. So it seems that the segue between loadVC and containterVC is done, but I don't see the mainVC screen that was set up as a rootViewController.

When I delete "bar.items = [item]" line the project is run as it should be, but there is no "Menu" button in the navigation bar.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a "container view" from the storyboard and embed a UINavigationController with your mainVC directly within the storyboard.

Anyway i think that `myNavigationController.addChildViewController(mainVC)` not necessary.

Also the bar items should be set to the mainVC's navigationItem, not the navigationController's one.

Also you did not mention what kind of segue are you using.

Comment: I'm using a "Show (e.g. Push)" segue. I know about setting it all in the storyboard, but this is one of my first projects and I'm trying to learn as many of the precoded functions and how they work as possible

Comment: Since you are using "Show (e.g. Push)" then which navigation controller you want to configure - the root one or the embedded one (myNavigationController)? I guess myNavigationController by reading your question. If so try to set the bar items to the mainVC's navigationItem, not the navigationController's one.

Comment: Setting bar items to the ViewController in the stack of UINavigationController and not the NavigationController itself is the answer! Thanks folk!